# What are good ways to implement FM Radio application for Android devices?

Tags: java, android

I need to develop FM Radio Application for Android devices. For this I have been searching for some insights about a kickstart tutorial or startup ideas but to my luck I couldn't find any thing functional.

What I have searched is a bunch of sample codes. Integrating them into a full functional application and running it on an emulator or a device doesn't fit into the scenario. It just stucks when a call is given to a native function to start radio and slaps me with

"No implementation found for native method" for the following call.

```
FmReceiverJNI.acquireFdNative("/dev/radio0");
```

Any ideas to implement it correctly?

**BTW:** I found [this](http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_apps_fm/commits/56e3111) code and currently following it.

**EDIT:** Since FM Radio application is totally vendor dependent. There are radio applications provided by specific vendors such as Samsung, HTC, QMobile etc. They have there own Radio applications. Can we register our application with them and catch events for radio functions such as Radio ON/OFF event, channel changed event, for how much time a specific channel has been used etc.

Comment: First of all it depends on what kind of streams are you going to play in radio. Depending on that you can go with `MediaPlayer` or build your own `FFMPEG` and use it in your app.

Comment: @Android-Developer: Thanks for your response, please have a look at my edited question.

Comment: As far as I know, there are broadcast receivers for Play/Pause/Stop for Media Playback in Android. Just to understand, are you talking about FM Radio like playing from 'radio frequency' or playing from some http streams?

Comment: Consider a scenario, user is playing radio and listening to a channel, he plays the channel for some time and then switches to another one. What I need is to get the frequency of that channel, time he has listened to it and the next channel he is currently listening. BTW how can we get Media playback Play/Pause/Stop events from another application?

Comment: Here are really good examples of how to deal with audio in android application : http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/index.html

Comment: @Android-Developer: thanks for your time and cooperation.